# Do you need to add an extra "," after the last member of a C enum?

Tags: c, enums

I saw an `enum` defined like below:

```
enum DAY{MON = 1, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN,};
```

...and it compiles successfully.

**Is adding an extra "," after the last element ok?**

Comment: Clearly it is.  This is a useful feature for programmers that write the enum members on a multiple lines (usually with a comment) and then, later, delete the last member.

Comment: Note that in C90, the trailing comma was not allowed.  C99 and later has an explicit rule that allows the trailing comma: _`enum identifieropt { enumerator-list , }`_ (the previous alternative in the grammar doesn't have that comma).

Comment: @HansPassant It's even more convenient for automated generation of enumerated constants.  The code generator can simply emit a trailing comma in all cases without having to consider if it's the last one.

Answer (score 5):

- No, you don't ***need*** the last comma.
- Yes, it is ***allowed*** to have an extra comma at the end.

---

This declaration:

```
enum DAY{MON = 1, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN,};
```

...is the same as:

```
enum DAY{MON = 1, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};
```

---

To understand the advantages of allowing this syntax, check out [**@chqrlie's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51687366/5660517).

Answer (score 5):

The trailing `,` in an `enum` definition or array initializer is optional, but quite useful, especially in lists spanning multiple lines.  It is allowed since C99 for reasons of symmetry as it avoids a different syntax for the last item in the list:

```
enum DAY {
    MON = 1,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
    SAT,
    SUN,
};
```

It makes it easier to generate array contents with scripts and avoids error prone situations where adding extra elements to an array but forgetting to add a comma might go unnoticed:

```
const char *osnames[] = {
    "CP/M",
    "MS/DOS",
    "Windows"
}
```

Adding extra items:

```
const char *osnames[] = {
    "CP/M",
    "MS/DOS",
    "Windows"
    "Linux",
    "OS/X"
};
```

Notice the missing comma in the middle of the list: the compiler parses the third string as `"WindowsLinux"` and the bug does not generate a syntax error.

With the trailing `,` on each line, it is much easier to add and delete items without modifying other lines. It is even more useful if lines are compiled conditionally as in this example:

```
const char *osnames[] = {
    "CP/M",
    "MS/DOS",
    "Windows",
#ifdef __UNIX__
    "Linux",
    "OS/X",
#endif
};
```